# Why is "Join Attributes by Location" reporting different CRS (and running forever)

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, spatial-join

I have a point feature layer with ~240,000 parcel centroids. I have a second feature layer containing ~9000 subdivision polygons. I want to assign the name of the associated subdivision as a new field to each point in the parcel centroid layer. The polygon layer is a shapefile containing a single field, the subdivision name. The point layer is a csv file containing 3 fields - the parcel ID, lat, lon and is loaded using layer->Add Delimited Text Layer.

The polygon layer is in WGS84/EPSG:4326. I have explicitly set the point layer to the same CRS. Everything looks sane on the map. I then try to do a spatial join: Vector->Data Management Tools->Join Attributes by Location. I set the target layer to the point layer, the join vector layer to the polygon layer. I set attribute summary to "Take attributes of first feature". I set the output shape file and click OK. I immediately get a warning message that the two layers have different CRS. But I have verified that are both EPSG:4326, as is the project CRS. I click OK and the progress bar immediately shows 15% and then life comes to a halt. The task monitor shows qgis running at 100% of CPU, but after several hours, it's still running at 100%, and the progress bar has not updated. I spatially indexed both layers.

Why did I get the different CRS message?

Why is this taking so long to run? (qgis 2.0.1 Dufour, Windows 7/64bit, Intel i7 2.4GHz)

Is there a better/different approach I should try?

Edit:
For what it's worth, ArcMap 10.2 did the spatial join in about 15 minutes (rough estimate - I wasn't actually timing it.)

If anyone wants to try this join, the data can be found [here](http://open-gov.info/PointPolygonJoin.zip)

Comment: I get this all the time and being new to QGIS still I would be interested in a clinical answer.

As a workaround I save the target layer as a new Shapefile and specify the CRS again to that of the join layer and it usually works.

Comment: I killed the job after 12 hours with no progress showing on the progress bar.

Comment: Storing the CSV in a database before running the job might be a good idea.

Comment: stored the csv as a shapefile, made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

How did you set the CRS of the point layer?

Rightclick -> `Save As ...` into another file with a different CRS is the only method working correct.

If you are unsure, turn on-the fly reprojection **off**. The layers must still overlap then.

Comment: Originally I just did a Rightclick->set crs, but I tried again as Morgan Ellingham wrote in the comments, and while that removes the warning about different CRS, the join still seems to hang. I allowed it to run for 12 hours and the progress bar hasn't changed and the program appears in the task monitor as "not responding".

Comment: What is the CRS of a layer that has been added via Add Delimited Text Layer? The csv file has no CRS, of course, and the dialog contains no place to set a CRS. I would have guessed it would default to the CRS of the project, but apparently it is treated as having no CRS at all.

Comment: In `Settings -> Options`, CRS tab you can choose to be asked for the CRS of new layers.

Comment: My project CRS was WGS84/EPSG:4326. The options setting for new layers is to use the project CRS. The other layer I was joining with was WGS84, yet I still got the warning when attempting the join until I saved the layer as a shapefile and re-loaded.

Comment: Can you save the CSV point layer as a new shapefile, with the right CRS, and try again? Maybe for a subset if it takes too long?

Just an off the cuff hunch but it might be a spatial indexing type thing with the large-ish amount of points.

Also, it might be a good idea to investigate spatial database options.

Comment: As commented above to Andre, I tried saving as a shapefile, but it made no difference. If I save a small piece of the csv file, I can load that as a layer, ignore the CRS message, and the spatial join works just fine. When I loaded the csv layer for the entire original file, I checked the box create spatial index, but that didn't seem to help.